# How to tell java to end the program after a statement is true?

Tags: java, if-statement

My homework assignment asks me to create a leap year program. I've made it, however, if both "if statements" are true, then they both print out. What the program should do is if the first "if statement" is true, then just print out the message that corresponds to the first "if statement and nothing else". However, if the first "if statement" is false, then do the second statement. And if the second statement is true, then just print out that message.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LeapYear {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput =  new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please type in a year greater than 1582");
        int year = userInput.nextInt();
        if(year < 1582)
            System.out.println("Sorry,please type in a year greater than 1582");
        int leapYear = year % 4;
        int leapYear2 = year % 100;
        int leapYear3 = year % 4;
        if(leapYear == 0)
             System.out.println(year+" Is a Leap Year");
        if(leapYear2 + leapYear3!= 0)
            System.out.println(year+"Is a Leap Year");
        else
            System.out.println(year+"Is not a Leap Year");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Check out [The if-then and if-then-else Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html).

Comment: Hey , you need to close this question by accepting 1 of the answers. You can click the check mark beside an answer to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to end the program or just the loop?  If it's the loop, make that second statement an `else if` statement:

```
if(leapYear == 0) {
    System.out.println(year+" Is a Leap Year");
}
else if(leapYear2 + leapYear3!= 0) {
    System.out.println(year+"Is a Leap Year");
}
else {
    etc.
}
```

Alternately, you could just combine the first two statements into an "or" statement:

```
if(leapYear == 0 || leapYear2 + leapYear3!= 0)
    System.out.println(year+" Is a Leap Year");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.exit(0)` to exit a program and You can also use `else if` to avoid two `if statement` to be executed at the same time:

```
    if(leapYear == 0){
        System.out.println(year+" Is a Leap Year");
    }
    else if(leapYear2 + leapYear3!= 0){
        System.out.println(year+"Is a Leap Year");
    } 
    else{
        System.out.println(year+"Is not a Leap Year");\
        System.exit(0); // to exit the program
    }
```

You can use many `else if` together like this following:

```
if(statement){
   //code
}
else if{
   // code
}
else if{
   // code
}
else{
   // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `return` statement.

Comment: (and braces around the blocks)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner userInput =  new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Please type in a year greater than 1582");
int year = userInput.nextInt();
if(year < 1582)
    System.out.println("Sorry,please type in a year greater than 1582");
    int leapYear = year % 4;
    int leapYear2 = year % 100;
    int leapYear3 = year % 4;
    if(leapYear == 0 || leapYear2 + leapYear3!= 0)
        System.out.println(year+" Is a Leap Year");    
    else
        System.out.println(year+"Is not a Leap Year");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(leapYear == 0) {
        System.out.println(year+" Is a Leap Year");
        return;
    }
    if(leapYear2 + leapYear3!= 0) {
        System.out.println(year+"Is a Leap Year");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(year+"Is not a Leap Year");
    }
```